# How to apply multi logic conditions between two dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, logic

I have  two dataframes like so:

df1

```
email         datetimecreated
1@1.com        2019-02-07 20:47:00
```

df2

```
email         datetimecreated
1@1.com        2019-02-12 20:47:00
```

I want to create the following logic:

```
1. check if email field in df2 is present in df1

if email address is present, then:

2. check if DatetimeCreated in df1 is greater than TODAY-90 days
```

IF both are TRUE do not append the row from df2 into df1.

I am doing the date check like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
df1 = df1[df1.DateTimeCreated >= (datetime.today() - timedelta(90))]
```

I am doing the email check like this:

```
boolean = session_final_101.EmailAddress.iat[0] in df3
```

How do I combine the two statements?

I tried this:

```
if boolean == False:
    Winner_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

but the boolean variable is always false I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `df2.append(df1.loc[df1.email.isin(df2.email)&(df1.datetimecreated.ge(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(90)))])` like this?

Comment: @anky_91 thank you for the answer, however your answer appends the results where as I am looking to not append if both conditions are met.

Comment: ok, so `df2.append(df1.loc[~df1.email.isin(df2.email)&(df1.datetimecreated.ge(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(90)))])` ??

Comment: @anky_91 your answer is still appending.